# C library for interfacing microcontroller and AT modem

Tags: gcc, embedded, microcontroller, modem, uart

I am working on some embedded system, where I use low-end uC, i.e. Atmega128.
My system also includes modem, driven via AT commands. I tried to look for any appropriate C library (for GCC), but couldn't find any. Although I know that putting "all" the possible AT command set into uC memory and so having "general purpose" library is unreasonable (and I just need around 30 commands for whole operation), I just need to get some suitable (i.e. **lightweight, robust**) control mechanism for handling transmitted and received UART strings in uC.
Does anybody know of any proven libraries or functions? Or maybe anyone could point me to some good resources/suggestions?

Comment: Do you want the ability to talk to an RS-232 interface, or do you already have this ability and need to capture the UART strings?

Comment: I don't need help with UART, I already make it working. I need help with program design. :)

Comment: See: http://git.ozlabs.org/?p=ppp.git;a=blob;f=chat/chat.c;hb=HEAD You didn't say what license.  I think the `chat.c` is BSD.

Comment: ATcommands just call for simple Serial transfer that's why a library not needed, did a lot myself with the SIM900 module and XBee's etc never thought of a need for it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you might be using this for the GSM or GPRS Modem interfacing, assuming as you have not specified application.

*Brief : GSM, GPRS modem is also using AT command inteface for communication with external controller.*

See detailed explanation here:

[Microchip AN1373 - Using PIC32 MCUs to Develop GSM/GPRS/GPS Solutions](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/01373A.pdf)

```
void UART_Buf(void)
{
        ch=SCI2D;
        if(rx_buffer[2] == 'O' && rx_buffer[3] =='K')
        {   
          rx_buffer[5] = '\0';
          msgindex=2;    // code for OK
          rx_wr_i=0;    
        }
        if(rx_buffer[2] == 'B' && rx_buffer[3] =='U' && rx_buffer[4] == 'S' && rx_buffer[5] =='Y')
        {   
          msgindex=3;    // Code for Busy
          rx_wr_i=0;    
        }
        
        if(rx_buffer[2] == 'N' && rx_buffer[3] =='O' && rx_buffer[4] == ' ' && rx_buffer[5] =='C' && rx_buffer[6] =='A' && rx_buffer[7] =='R'&& rx_buffer[8] =='R' && rx_buffer[9] =='I' && rx_buffer[10] =='E' && rx_buffer[11] =='R')
        {   
          msgindex=3;    // Code for  No Carrier
          rx_wr_i=0;    
        }
        if(rx_buffer[2] == 'E' && rx_buffer[3] =='R' && rx_buffer[4] == 'R' && rx_buffer[5] =='O' && rx_buffer[6] =='R' )
        {   
          msgindex=4;    // Code for Error
            rx_wr_i=0;  
        } 
         if(rx_buffer[2]=='+' && rx_buffer[3]=='C' && rx_buffer[4] == 'M' && rx_buffer[5] =='S' )
        {   
          msgindex=3;
        } 
         if(rx_buffer[2]=='+' && rx_buffer[3]=='C' && rx_buffer[4] == 'M' && rx_buffer[5] =='E' )
        {   
          msgindex=3;
        }     
        if(rx_buffer[2]=='+' && rx_buffer[3]=='C' && rx_buffer[4] == 'M' && rx_buffer[5] =='G' && rx_buffer[6]== 'R')
        {   
          msgindex=6;
        }
        
        if(rx_buffer[2]=='E' && rx_buffer[3]=='R' && rx_buffer[4] == 'R' && rx_buffer[5] =='O' && rx_buffer[6] == 'R')
        {   
          msgindex=3;
        } 
        
        if(rx_buffer[2]=='+' && rx_buffer[3]=='C' && rx_buffer[4] == 'S' && rx_buffer[5] =='Q' )
        {
          msgindex=7;
        }
        
        if(rx_buffer[2]=='+' && rx_buffer[3]=='C' && rx_buffer[4] == 'O' && rx_buffer[5] =='L'&& rx_buffer[6] =='P' )
        {
         msgindex=8;
        }
        if(ch == '\r')
          linefeed++;
}
```

and in ISR

```
__interrupt void isrVsci2rx(void)
{
      SCI2S1_RDRF = 0;
      rx_buffer[rx_ack++]= SCI2D;
      if(rx_ack>RX_BUFFER_MASK)
        rx_ack=0;
      UART_Buf();
      rx_length++;
  
}
```

check ***msgindex*** and ***linefeed*** to know response received.